# How many unique possibilities for $n\times n$ matrix are there?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

When given a $n \times n$ matrix (for simplicity let's say $n=3$) how many unique possibilities are there to fill the entries with a set of $m$ numbers (again for simplicity let's say $m=10$). With unique I mean excluding rotations and mirror images.

Comment: Are all the $m$ numbers different? Are you allowed repeats? And, just to be clear, you are considering rotations and flips to produce the same grid and not a different one, right?

Comment: Lets say all numbers are different and repeats are allowed. Yes the grid stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we allow numbers to repeat in the grid, then this is exactly what Burnside's lemma helps you do. It says basically that the number of distinct grids is equal to the average, per symmetry, of the number of grids which are completely unaltered by that symmetry.

So, there are $8$ symmetries. Those are:

- Rotate $180^\circ$. For a grid to be completely unaltered after applying this symmetry, there are 4 pairs of cells which must have the same number in them, while the middle cell is unrestricted. So there are $m^5$ unaltered grids
- Rotate $90^\circ$, in two different ways. For a grid to be completely unaltered, all the corner cells must be equal, all the side cells must be equal, and the center can be whatever it wants. $m^3$ unaltered grids for each rotation
- Flip (mirror image), in four different ways. For a grid to be completely unaltered, the three cells along the symmetry axis are unrestricted, but the remaining six cells go into three equal pairs. So there are $m^6$ unaltered grids for each flip
- Doing nothing (don't forget this one, it's important). In this case there are $m^{9}$ grids which are unaltered.

The average of these is
$$
\frac{m^5+2m^3+4m^6+m^9}{8}
$$
and that's your answer.

For general $n$, you can follow the exact same recipe. For any $n>1$ there are the same $8$ symmetries. However, the calculation of unaltered grids will depend on whether $n$ is even, as that affects how many cells are sent to themselves by the symmetry (in particular, for even $n$, the diagonal flips and the horizontal / vertical flips cannot be treated as one).